# How can I convert this JSON array to Python dictionary? json.loads is returning type error

Tags: python, arrays, json, api

I'm working with a new stock market API -- the API returns realtime quotes for particular tickers upon the user submitting a subscription request. This is the format of the quote data that is returned:

```
import json

test_array = 'a[{"e":"md","d":{"quotes":[{"id":2065891,"timestamp":"2021-05-31T15:01:27.094Z","contractId":2065891,"entries":{"Bid":{"price":4193.5,"size":24},"TotalTradeVolume":{"size":89096},"Offer":{"price":4193.75,"size":50},"LowPrice":{"price":4192.25},"Trade":{"price":4193.5,"size":2},"OpenInterest":{"size":2600561},"OpeningPrice":{"price":4206.5},"HighPrice":{"price":4210.25},"SettlementPrice":{"price":4202.5}}}]}}]'

test_array_to_json = json.loads(test_array)
```

This is the error that's returned:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bentp\Desktop\Albert the Bot\jsonplayground.py", line 3, in <module>
    test_array_to_dict = json.loads(test_array)
  File "C:\users\bentp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\users\bentp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\users\bentp\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Anyone know what's going on, and how I can get this to work to return a python dictionary? thanks so much. I am newbie coder, if you can't tell already. Thanks again!

Comment: The "a" at beginning of the json is not allowed. What should it mean?

Answer (score 2):

Remove the first `a` in the data:

```
import json

test_array = '[{"e":"md","d":{"quotes":[{"id":2065891,"timestamp":"2021-05-31T15:01:27.094Z","contractId":2065891,"entries":{"Bid":{"price":4193.5,"size":24},"TotalTradeVolume":{"size":89096},"Offer":{"price":4193.75,"size":50},"LowPrice":{"price":4192.25},"Trade":{"price":4193.5,"size":2},"OpenInterest":{"size":2600561},"OpeningPrice":{"price":4206.5},"HighPrice":{"price":4210.25},"SettlementPrice":{"price":4202.5}}}]}}]'

test_array_to_json = json.loads(test_array)
```

worked for me